# How to fix this: C++ switch statement

Tags: c++

I have problems on my switch statements in `// number of crowns` and `// frame color`

This is my output [image]

how can i show my `cout` to output the `frame_color` and `number_crowns` (on `// number of crowns` and `// frame color`)?

btw im using `CodeBlocks`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length, width, number_crowns;
    double cost;
    int frameType;
    int yes_no;
    int colorSelection;
    string frame_color;
    string type;

    cout << "Input length and width of the picture: ";
    cin >> length >> width;

    cout << "1(spacebar)regular" << endl
         << "2(spacebar)fancy" << endl
         << "(regular/fancy)Enter type of frame: ";
    cin >> frameType >> type;

    cout << "1 = with" << endl
         << "2 = without" << endl
         << "(with/without)With color/Without?";
    cin >> colorSelection;

    cout << "1 = yes" << endl
         << "2 = no" << endl
         << "(yes/no)Do you want to put crowns? ";
    cin >> yes_no;

    cost = (2 * 0.1) * (length + width);               // cost in length and width of the frame
    cost += (0.02 * (length * width));                 // cost per square inch

    switch(frameType)
    {                                 // type of frame
    case '1':
        cost += 0.15;
        break;
    case '2':
        cost += 0.25;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "wrong input!";
    }

    switch(colorSelection)
    {                           // frame color
    case '1':
        cost += 0.10;
        cout << "Enter desired frame color: ";
        cin >> frame_color;
        break;
    case '2':
        cost += 0;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "wrong input!";
    }

    switch(yes_no)
    {                                 // number of crowns
    case '1':
        cout << "Input number of crowns: ";
        cin >> number_crowns;
        cost += (number_crowns * 0.35);
        break;
    case '2':
        cost =+ 0;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "wrong input!";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "\n\nFrame type: " << type << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Frame colour: " << frame_color << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "Total frame cost: " << cost << "\n" << endl;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

NEWEST UPDATE W***
wahahaha

how can i show my `cout` to output the `frame_color` and `number_crowns` (on `// number of crowns` and `// frame color`)?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int length, width, number_crowns;
    double cost;
    char frameType;
    char yes_no;
    char colorSelection;
    string frame_color;
    string type;

    cout << "Input length and width of the picture: ";
    cin >> length >> width;

    cout << "(regular/fancy) Enter type of frame: ";
    cin >> frameType >> type;

    cout << "(with/without) With color/Without?";
    cin >> colorSelection;

    cout << "(yes/no) Do you want to put crowns? ";
    cin >> yes_no;

    cost = (2 * 0.1) * (length + width);               // cost in length and width of the frame
    cost += (0.02 * (length * width));                 // cost per square inch

    cout << "\nFrame type: " << frameType << type << "\n" << endl;
    switch(frameType)
    {                                 // type of frame
    case 'regular':
        cost += 0.15;
        break;
    case 'fancy':
        cost += 0.25;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "wrong input!";
    }

    cout << "\nFrame colour: " << frame_color << "\n" << endl;
    switch(colorSelection)
    {                           // frame color
    case 'with':
        cost += 0.10;
        cout << "Enter desired frame color: ";
        cin >> frame_color;
        break;
    case 'without':
        cost += 0;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "wrong input!";
    }

    switch(yes_no)
    {                                 // number of crowns
    case 'yes':
        cout << "Input number of crowns: ";
        cin >> number_crowns;
        cost += (number_crowns * 0.35);
        break;
    case 'no':
        cost =+ 0;
        break;
    default:
        cout << "wrong input!";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "\nTotal frame cost: " << cost << "\n" << endl;
}
```

NEWEST output 
[image]

Comment: Your `case` labels are wrong - you're comparing `int` values with `char` literals - get rid of the single quotes, i.e. `case '1':` -> `case 1:`. Also, for future reference, you might want to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Please stop posting pictures of text, post text as text instead.

Comment: oooh thanks a lot!

Comment: Please learn how to write and use functions. There is way too much code in `main`.

Comment: @ElecTreeFrying you should output `frame_color` and `number_crowns` just before the call to `switch`. See the example in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variables `frameType`, `yes_no` and `colorSelection` are declared as `int` and you are doing the comparison against `char` in your `switch`.

You should remove the quotes.

e.g.:

```
cout<<"My frame type: "<<frameType<<endl;
switch(frameType)
{                                 // type of frame
case 1:
    cost += 0.15;
    break;
case 2:
    cost += 0.25;
    break;
default:
    cout << "wrong input!";
}
```

Note that you can display your variable before the `switch` statement

Comment: @ElecTreeFrying regarding your update about the display of your variable. You should simply do that before the call to the switch (see the code above).

Answer (score 0):

Case statements check to see whether the input value matches some constant.

In your case you are checking to see whether the `int` value for `frameType` which will be 1 or 0 is the same as the constant value for '1'.

This '1' (wich is a `char` type) will actually automatically convert to an integer when compared with an integer, but it will convert to an integer based on the [ascii table](http://www.asciitable.com/) so it will become the integer `49`.

So when it all compiles its as if you had written something like this:

```
switch (frameType) {
case 49:
  // Clearly frametype won't be 49 so this won't happen
case 50:
  // Same problem
```

These hidden conversions can be a big pain for everyone and so most people will turn on compiler warnings that will stop the compilation if these 'implicit conversions' happen.

If you compile with all warnings turned on and treat them as errors most compilers would catch this sort of thing for you! Where I work this is the default mode of compilation because we all make these mistakes ... lets say occasionally.